# ng-file-upload not working with localstorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm using ng-file-upload for uploading image in my project but 
whenever I implement `localStorage` using `AuthFactory.setToken({token: "secret_token", expires: 'time'});` `ng-file-upload` fails to send image to server. It does not conflict with `AuthFactory.setUser(user_obj)`

```
.factory('AuthFactory', ['LSFactory', function(LSFactory) {

    var userKey = 'user';
    var tokenKey = 'token';

    var AuthAPI = {

        isLoggedIn: function() {
            return this.getUser() === null ? false : true;
        },

        getUser: function() {
            return LSFactory.get(userKey);
        },

        setUser: function(user) {
            return LSFactory.set(userKey, user);
        },

        getToken: function() {
            return LSFactory.get(tokenKey);
        },

        setToken: function(token) {
            return LSFactory.set(tokenKey, token);
        },

        deleteAuth: function() {
            LSFactory.delete(userKey);
            LSFactory.delete(tokenKey);
        }

    };

    return AuthAPI;

}])

.factory('LSFactory', [function() {

    var LSAPI = {

        clear: function() {
            return localStorage.clear();
        },

        get: function(key) {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
        },

        set: function(key, data) {
            return localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
        },

        delete: function(key) {
            return localStorage.removeItem(key);
        },

        getAll: function() {
            var books = [];
            var items = Object.keys(localStorage);

            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if (items[i] !== 'user' || items[i] != 'token') {
                    books.push(JSON.parse(localStorage[items[i]]));
                }
            }

            return books;
        }

    };

    return LSAPI;

}])
```

Comment: Provide more info please. What is the problem when sending, show the ng-file-upload code. Ideally provide example on Plunker or similar.

Comment: problem solved!! Thanks